# How to use a C-like enum with diesel

Tags: postgresql, rust, enums, rust-diesel

I have a `users` table that I'm trying to add a `role` field to with Diesel:

```rust
#[derive(Debug, Clone, Queryable, Insertable)]
pub struct User {
    // other fields
    pub role: Role,
}

#[derive(Debug, Clone, Copy, PartialEq, Eq, AsExpression)]
#[sql_type = "diesel::sql_types::VarChar"]
pub enum Role {
    User,
    Admin,
}

/// manual impls for FromSql<VarChar, Pg>, ToSql<VarChar, Pg> and FromSqlRow<VarChar, Pg>
```

For compatibility reasons, I'd like these to be represented in the database as varchars (`"user"` and `"admin"`), but would like to use an enum on the Rust side for extra type safety.

However, with the setup I currently have, I get:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `Role: Queryable<Text, Pg>` is not satisfied
  --> src/state/database/users.rs:47:32
   |
47 |         self.exec(|conn| users.load(conn)).await
   |                                ^^^^ the trait `Queryable<Text, Pg>` is not implemented for `Role`
   |
   = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `Queryable<(diesel::sql_types::Uuid, Text, Text, diesel::sql_types::Timestamp, Text), Pg>` for `(model::types::UserId, model::types::Email, model::types::PasswordHash, NaiveDateTime, Role)`
   = note: 1 redundant requirement hidden
   = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `Queryable<(diesel::sql_types::Uuid, Text, Text, diesel::sql_types::Timestamp, Text), Pg>` for `user::User`
   = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `LoadQuery<PooledConnection<diesel::r2d2::ConnectionManager<diesel::PgConnection>>, user::User>` for `schema::users::table`
```

From what I understand, in diesel, `VarChar` and `Text` are the same type (i.e. aliased). If I change all of the `VarChar`s to `Text`s in my impls, the error persists.

I'm confident it's not the other fields/field order because if I replace `Role` with a plain `String`, it works.

I feel like I must be missing something, this seems like fairly common behaviour. Perhaps there's another trait I need to implement?

FWIW, my schema for the users table looks like:

```rust
table! {
    users (id) {
        id -> Uuid,
        email -> Varchar,
        password_hash -> Varchar,
        created_at -> Timestamp,
        role -> Varchar,
    }
}
```

Using postgres 14, rust 1.57, diesel 1.4.8

Comment: *"Perhaps there's another trait I need to implement?"* - the error says that the trait [`Queryable<Text, Pg>`](https://docs.diesel.rs/diesel/deserialize/trait.Queryable.html) is not implemented for `Role`.

Comment: Please add the following information to your question as it's otherwise hard to answer it: Which database system are you using? Which rustc and which diesel version are you using.

Comment: Manually implementing `Queryable` seems to have fixed it, thanks! I didn't try this initially beacuse I already use some wrapper types (e.g. `UserId` is a thin wrapper around `Uuid`), and for those types deriving `AsExpression`, `FromSqlRow` and manually implementing `FromSql` and `ToSql` was sufficient. Do you know why enums behave differently here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to derive [`FromSqlRow`](https://docs.diesel.rs/1.4.x/diesel/deserialize/trait.FromSqlRow.html#deriving) as well. It will generate the necessary `FromSqlRow` and `Queryable` impl for your type.